# Python multiprocessing in flask

Tags: python, flask, parallel-processing

This question has probably been asked, and more than likely answered, but I don't know where to find it here.

Problem: I have a router for python's flask, that takes a while to process data for each call. I need to make each of the calls to the routes be a thread in itself so it doesn't have to wait for the requests to be loaded.

Comment: Do you want to use multi-threading for a single request?  Or do you want each request to be a separate process/thread?

Comment: Each request should be a separate thread.

Comment: I'll accept a redirect to an existing thread as an answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Flask` comes with a built-in development web server, [but you shouldn't be using it in production](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/deploying/#deployment-options).

To get cool features like separate processes for each request and static file serving, you need to run an actual web service and a WSGI service in front of your `Flask` application.

The `Flask` docs provide [several examples on how to set that up](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/deploying/#deployment-options).  Popular Web Server/WSGI combinations are Apache/mod_wsgi and Nginx/Gunicorn, but there are many other options.

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, there are specialized tools to do this ([celery](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) seems to be the best), but if someone just wants to quickly get something set up and working, here is my approach which only uses Python's `multiprocessing` module:

```
from flask import Flask
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

def detachedProcessFunction(wait_time):
    i=0
    while i<wait_time:
        i = i+1
        print "loop running %d" % i
        time.sleep(1)

@app.route('/start')
def start():
    global p
    p = Process(target=detachedProcessFunction, args=(15))
    p.start()
    return render_template('layout.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

NOTE: This method won't work for running object functions (e.g. `obj.objFunc()`). You will get an `EOFError: Ran out of input inside a class`. In this case, you should create the object inside a non-object/standalone function and pass the arguments you need to create the object. For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44704086/eoferror-ran-out-of-input-inside-a-class)

Comment: using this , it seems the flask application still wont be available during that timeout period of 15 secs @DankMasterDan

Comment: @Uddhav what timeout period are you referring to? I did not see any time where the flask application was unavailable..

Comment: It's blocking. The application wont be available.

Answer (score 5):

A really good way of setting this up would be to use "uwsgi" as your application server (and protocol) and Nginx as your front-end proxy.  These are super quick, scalable, handle threading, and it is one of the Flask-recommended methods.  Though the flask documentation provides the basic config, this guide is one I've used and it gives a much-more in-depth walkthrough for installation.  They are using Ubuntu, but with minor changes (to the install commands) it will work on most Linux flavors.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04