# Using threads in flask web app

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, thread-safety

I am developing a web app which has a service/task which might take a long time to finish. I am new to python and read that python has GIL, which means at one time only one thread can run irrespective of number of cores.

my pseudo code is like this

```
def service_xxx(self, data):
    thread = ThreadXXX(data)
    thread.start()
    self.threads[data.id] = thread
```

My questions is what happens when 100 requests comes ? Will flask framework run 100 user threads concurrently using all cores or its going to run 100 threads on single cores ?

Comment: You don't have 100 cores, do you?

Comment: Now serious. GIL is the reason I personally don't rely on threads when I need concurrency. I prefer multiprocessing. See  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35616639/7699691 for more information.

Comment: You can integrate [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) with Flask

Comment: I am trying to understand how flask is handling these threads and also how requests are handled in each threads or not?

Answer (score 0):

Python (CPython) is not optimized for thread framework.You can keep allocating more resources and it will try spawning/queuing new threads and overloading the cores. You need to make a design change here:

Process based design:

1. Either use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module
2. Make use of [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) and make this task run separately
3. Spawn a [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Or if you still want to stick to threads:

1. Switch to [PyPy](http://pypy.org) (faster compared to CPython)
2. Switch to [PyPy-STM](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/stm.html) (totally does away with GIL)